# Need help (starting place) with basic blend WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, expression-blend

I am trying to learn WPF, and like anything programming I do, I always try to create something fun for my self so the project is not boring.

So I want to have a program that starts up with three boxes fadding in one after another. When a box is clicked have all the boxes fade out and a separate WPF user control I create fade in. Then have a button to fade that out and get the three boxes again to fade back in.

Now I do have visual studio 2010 and blend 4. I am able to create a animations like the ones above in blend but the problem is it goes from one animation to the next not stopping. And I have no way in visual studio to program events or anything else because the WPF form in visual studio looks white (nothing I do in blend shows up, it is only viewable in blend).

I am looking for some good tutorials or links to help me do the above. I don't think it would be that hard I just need a step in the right direction. I am not looking for code here because I don't want someone to do it for me, rather I just want help. And if you have any other related tips to share please do.

So thank you, and I know this is sort of a different post but thank you for any insight you have and any links you share.

Comment: I think you're gonna need some code here my friend.  There are many ways to do what you're asking and it's going to largely depend on your current approach.  Stick some code in the question and you'll probably get more help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to walk before you can run, and in this case that means learning some of the basics of xaml before trying to work with timelines, triggers and click events. I would start with the Lynda videos (they're free) found here: http://www.lynda.com/Expression-Blend-tutorials/getting-started-with/384-2.html